# horizontal form using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi all Im trying to implement a horizontal form using twitters bootstrap, but for some reason the labels keep displaying as block level items and not floating left next to the text box. My code is below can anyone help.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/prettyPhoto/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/document.ready.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/js/prettyPhoto/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/css/loggedin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body screen_capture_injected="true">
    <form method="post" action="feedback.aspx" id="form1" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>Feedback &amp; comments</h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <p>Please use the form below to give us your feedback, comments, and suggestions to improve the site.</p>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Feedback</legend>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="MainBodyContent_TxtEmail">Email</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input name="ctl00$MainBodyContent$TxtEmail" type="text" value="" id="MainBodyContent_TxtEmail" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="MainBodyContent_TxtEmail">Name</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input name="ctl00$MainBodyContent$TxtName" type="text" id="MainBodyContent_TxtName" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="MainBodyContent_TxtEmail">Comments</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <textarea name="ctl00$MainBodyContent$TxtComments" rows="2" cols="20" id="MainBodyContent_TxtComments" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainBodyContent$SendFeedback" value="Send" id="MainBodyContent_SendFeedback" class="btn">
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to work with columns, you can see an example in the [documentation of Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) (scroll down to Horizontal forms).

Code example:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks I'm reading O'Reillys book on bootstrap and it doesn't mention that but it works great

Comment: Awesome. If this has helped you out, please upvote and mark this as solution!